# Following short python code works but I was expecting an error

Tags: python

```
class MyClass: pass
def myfunction(): print('hi')

MyClass.foo = myfunction
obj = MyClass()
obj.foo = myfunction

MyClass.foo()
obj.foo()
```

I'm learning python and can't understand how the last two lines work without giving any contradicting error.
I'm assigning and calling same myfunction first with the class object and then with instance object and what I understand is that while calling a method with instance object, python implicitly passes the instance to the method. So I was expecting one of the last two lines to work but not both. But here both works fine. I'm confused.

Comment: Are you familiar with what [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) are? `obj.foo` only evaluates to a method object if `obj` _does not_ have an attribute named `foo`, but `MyClass` _does_. If `obj` does have an attribute `foo`, then `obj.foo` is just a normal attribute lookup, no different than if `obj.foo = 3`.

Comment: Thanks @Brian61354270 ! I'll certainly read about descriptors tomorrow. But meanwhile I modified the code by deleting 3rd line and 2nd-last line and it still works fine. Is it in-line with what you described ?

class MyClass: pass
def myfunction(): print('hi')

obj = MyClass()
obj.foo = myfunction
obj.foo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first approximation<sup>1</sup>, when you write

```
obj.foo
```

Python attempts to lookup `foo` by

1. checking whether `obj` has an attributed named `foo`, then
2. checking whether `obj`'s class (`obj.__class__`, here `MyClass`) has an attribute `foo`.

If in the first step, an attribute name `foo` is found, then that object gets returned. It does not matter *what* that object is (be it a function object or anything else), it just gets returned. This is what is happening in your code: `obj` has an attribute named `foo`, so that object gets returned - `MyClass.foo` is never considered.

If `obj` does not have an attribute `foo`, then we reach the second step. Here, some special behavior kicks in: the [Descriptor Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). If `obj.__class__` has an attribute named `foo`, then before returning that object, Python first checks whether `foo` is a descriptor. If it is, then instead of returning `foo`, Python will return `foo.__get__(obj)`. *This* is how methods works. Methods are just function attributes on the class that were accessed through the descriptor protocol.

If instead you only wrote

```
class MyClass: 
    pass

def myfunction(): 
    print('hi')

MyClass.foo = myfunction

obj = MyClass()
obj.foo()
```

then you would have a problem. Now, `obj` *does not* have an attribute named `foo`, so accessing `obj.foo` looks up `foo` on `MyClass`. `MyClass` does have an attribute named `foo`, which is bound to `myfunction`. `myfunction`, like all function objects, is a descriptor, so Python calls  `myfunction.__get__(obj)`, which returns a bound-method object. This bound-method object is a callable that will try to pass `obj` to `myfunction` when it's invoked. Since `myfunction` doesn't accept any parameters, this will produce an error as you originally suspected:

```
TypeError: myfunction() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>The complete attribute lookup process is much more complicated. See [3.3.2. Customizing attribute access](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) from the Python Data Model docs for the bigger picture.</sub>